# extract pointers , variable from a expression in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a code in which extracts variable from expressions

eg:-

```
expr = "a + b *2"
expr.split(/\W+/).reject{ |s| (s.to_i.to_s == s || s.to_f.to_s == s || s == "")
```

but if `expr` has pointers

eg:-

```
expr = "*a + b -*c"
```

It removes `*` from it. is there any way so that I can extract pointers also?

Answer (score 3):

Rather than `split`/`reject`, I'd recommend `scan`:

```
expr.scan(/\*?\w+/)

#=> ["*a", "b", "*c"]
```

The regular expression looks for an optional `*` followed by one or more word chars.